# Maven compilation failes (but compilation under Eclipse is successful)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

While building my web project from **Eclipse**, everything is fine: **no errors, no warnings**.

However while building project with **Maven** it **failes**. Below is the output form `mvn compile`:

> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web>mvn
>   compile -e
>   + Error stacktraces are turned on. [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building traffic_web [INFO]
>   task-segment: [compile] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] [resources:resources
>   {execution: default-resources}]
>   [WARNING] Using platform encoding
>   (Cp1250 actually) to copy filtered
>   resources, i.e. build is platform
>   dependent! [INFO] skip non existing
>   resourceDirectory
>   c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\main\resources
>   [INFO] [compiler:compile {execution:
>   default-compile}] [INFO] Compiling 22
>   source files to
>   c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\target\classes
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Compilation failure
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\Encryptor.java:[7,15]
>   sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun propriet
>   ary API and may be removed in a future
>   release
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\Session.java:[3,25]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not
>   exis t
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\Session.java:[15,21]
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : class
>   HttpSession location: class
>   traffic_web.tools.Session
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\ServletContextListenerInitializer.java:[6,20]
>   package javax. servlet does not exist
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\ServletContextListenerInitializer.java:[7,20]
>   package javax. servlet does not exist
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\ServletContextListenerInitializer.java:[8,20]
>   package javax. servlet does not exist
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\ServletContextListenerInitializer.java:[10,58]
>   cannot find s ymbol symbol: class
>   ServletContextListener public class
>   ServletContextListenerInitializer
>   implements ServletContextListener {
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\ServletContextListenerInitializer.java:[12,33]
>   cannot find s ymbol symbol  : class
>   ServletContextEvent location: class
>   traffic_web.tools.ServletContextListenerInitializer
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\ServletContextListenerInitializer.java:[15,35]
>   cannot find s ymbol symbol  : class
>   ServletContextEvent location: class
>   traffic_web.tools.ServletContextListenerInitializer
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\controller\BoardController.java:[9,25]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not
>   exist
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\controller\BoardController.java:[87,29]
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : class
>   HttpServletResponse location: class
>   traffic_web.controller.BoardController
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\controller\BoardController.java:[116,37]
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : class
>   HttpServletResponse location: class
>   traffic_web.controller.BoardController
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\Encryptor.java:[27,15]
>   sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprie
>   tary API and may be removed in a
>   future release
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\Session.java:[17,27]
>   cannot access
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpSe rvletRequest
>   class file for
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>   not found
>               return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); //
>   true == allow create
>
> c:\Users\jwa\Desktop\tets\traffic_web\src\traffic_web\tools\ServletContextListenerInitializer.java:[17,8]
>   cannot find sy mbol symbol  : class
>   ServletContext location: class
>   traffic_web.tools.ServletContextListenerInitializer
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Trace
>   org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException:
>   Compilation failure
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:55
>   6)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.jav
>   a:387)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation failure
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
>           ... 17 more [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 1 second [INFO]
>   Finished at: Mon Jun 28 21:56:25 CEST
>   2010 [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/254M
>
> ### [INFO]

My POM file looks like that:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>masters.traffic</groupId>
  <artifactId>traffic_web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>traffic_web</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>

    ...

</project>
```

Can Someone help me how to fix that ?

Regards

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You haven't added the servlet classes as dependencies. There are apparently present per default in Eclipse, which is why it works to compile from there. Add the following to you pom (before `<build>...`, taken from [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/web-sect-adding-j2ee-depend.html)):

```
<dependencies>
  [...]
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```