# Spring @WebListener is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I use Spring 4 and want to use `ServletContextListener` . When I add `@WebListener` annotation to the class eclipse IDE shows compile errors. Also the implementation also shows compile error.

`public class MyContextListener  implements ServletContextListener { // this shows compiler` error underlying the `ServletContextListener`

I have added spring-web as well . spring version is 4.0.3.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>            
    </dependency>
```

can any one tell me where can be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve compilation issues in Eclipse:

Add the latest version of servlet-api.jar to your build path.

Add the servlet dependencies in your pom too:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

**See Also:**

[Maven compilation failes (but compilation under Eclipse is successful)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135871/maven-compilation-failes-but-compilation-under-eclipse-is-successful)

Comment: Thanks a LOTT... Now I can implements the Listener. but the annotation does not available @WebListener.. What  can I do for that ?

Comment: add servlet-api.jar to your classpath. updated my answer wrt your comments

Comment: eclipse IDE gives error . `Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0` for version 3.0.

Comment: Thanks it solved. but new version `3.1.0` can be found in mvn repo.

Comment: Yes, then, you could definitely add that. I have not checked out the things that have shaped up from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0.

Comment: How ever Thank you very much. I think, adding this solved entire problem. ( it seemed that maven compiler has some caches..if those not removed, expected final build may not come. earlier my project was building failed... . may be I am wrong.). Thansks BatScream

Answer (score 1):

`@javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener` annotation is part of `servlet-api` not spring framework, if you are using `Tomcat` go to `Project -> Properties -> Project Facets` in the right panel choose `RunTimes` then check the Tomcat server instance you are using then apply.
after that if you go to `java build path -> libraries` you will see `Apache Tomcat vXX` added to the libraries.
or you might download `servlet-api` and add it to your classpath

Comment: Yes, with that configurations of eclipse, annotation is now supported.. Thanks very much... :)

Answer (score 0):

@WebListener is annotation from javax.servlet package, did you add it in your maven pom file?